# Dragging and dropping images from Firefox into Microsoft Powerpoint

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, draggable, powerpoint

I am trying to make a web page which allows users to drag and drop images into Microsoft Office applications, specifically Powerpoint.

By default (as of FF3.5), Firefox will insert the source URL when an image is dropped rather than the image itself. After adding the following Javascript/jQuery code (derived from https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DragDrop/Drag_Operations),

```
$('img').attr('draggable', true).bind('dragstart', function (event) {
    event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'copy';
});
```

dragging and dropping works from Firefox to Word and Excel, but not to PowerPoint. For an example of what happens, see http://slides.html5rocks.com/#drag-and-drop.  I have tested this with FF3.6 and FF9.

How can I make it work with PowerPoint?

Comment: I doubt you can do anything within your page to make this work. Maybe something can be done from within PowerPoint.

Answer (score 1):

## Status quo

Sadly there is nothing you can do from within your *browser* and the application to enable drop support for *PowerPoint*.

This is something that needs to supported at source level in PowerPoint (and it seem to be if you don't drop the image on an existing element but right outside the slide frame you want to drop it onto - but probably depending on version).

If it (for some reason still) does not support the image part of the drop but just the link (and if there is no option provided for changing this behavior) there is little to do but to hope Microsoft will update PowerPoint with this support in the future, - or - check the following options for work-arounds if needed:

## Add-ins

You can look into writing an *add-in* (or possibly just use a macro - you might need to [lower security to medium [PDF]](http://myweb.tiscali.co.uk/chemteach/pgce_1/macro.pdf) for macros) for PowerPoint that will take the link that is dropped and replace it with the image the link refers to.

[Here is one place to get you started making add-ins if this is a viable option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668192.aspx).

[Here is a commercial framework that makes creating add-ins very simple](http://www.add-in-express.com/docs/net.php).

(disclaimer in this regard: I am here *assuming* this will be possible due to [add-ins such as this](http://skp.mvps.org/liveweb.htm) which allow you to show a live web page inside PP).

## Pipe-line / work process

There is also the option of injecting a third-party applications in the pipe-line to do screen snapshots of the image and have it inserted automatically into PP.

[SnagIt is such an application](http://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html) (and there are probably others) and it has free extensions that will allow you to integrate "snags" [directly with PowerPoint](http://www.techsmith.com/snagit-accessories.html).

Or (the perhaps too obvious option): simply copy the image in browser and paste it into PowerPoint.

Comment: I figured that there wouldn't be a way to do it directly from the webpage, but I certainly will consider writing an add-in. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just drag'n'drop outside the boundaries of the ppt slide (to make sure you're not dropping on a predefined textbox) - and release the mouse button -no coding needed!

Firefox drag will drop the image at the center of te ppt slide.

Answer (score 0):

What is your version of Powerpoint?
It's very important because image format support may be lacking.
If that's the case your code needs a minimum version warning addition.
Could also ask to convert image to suitable format.

It may even be the case that it's impossible to the version of Powerpoint you're using to support this in the way you want.

You could try to use html code.

This code might help you:
http://classroomtech.org.uk/2008/08/drag-and-drop-in-powerpoint/

Other possibilities are OLE object with a link to a image.

Could check how other Microsoft applications, that do something similar, handle things.

If that doesn't work you could try to generate an OLE object with a link to the image in it.